# Convert PHP MySQL Web Page using PhoneGap

Tags: php, mysql, forms, submit, cordova

What's the best way to convert a PHP web app (with server-side MySQL database support) to a SmartPhone App (Android, iPhone, etc.) without having to re-write the web app natively on each SmartPhone platform?  Can a tool like PhoneGap help with this?

For example, let's say I have a web application that uses PHP and MySQL.  Like many PHP/MySQL projects, I simply have a web page that captures data entered by a user in an HTML form that is submitted to PHP which, in turn, runs SQL statements to store that data into the database.  The PHP also generates web pages to display data (i.e. SELECT statements). It runs great on any web browser inlcuding the browser in my Android phone, but I'd like to convert it using a tool like PhoneGap so that it runs faster, appears more professional/seamless and can be easily distributed through the Android Market or iPhone App Store.

To further simplify my question, I guess what I'm really after is this: How can I convert an html page with a form so that when the app (converted html page) runs on the smartphone, data entered and submitted by the user can be processed on my web server?  Has anyone tried this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhoneGap can help big time, but there are some considerable changes that you need make. Also, you need to decide your requirements and make sure that PhoneGap can meet those requirements.

Comment: so it sounds like I will need to re-write the php script to html5/Javascript/CSS.   Looks like HTML5 gives me a local database and the ability to connect to server side database for "syncing". Then I can use a tool like PhoneGap to convert it.  Or just leave it as a web app since it will function on all platforms running HTML5. It looks like HTML5 will be supported by most platforms in the near future.   Thanks for the replies!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Adobe Air but it's a little slow.. and for iphone .. you can make a iphone web app .. and to tell u how good an iphone web app is .. The Netflix Application is basically an iPhone web app.